# Fluid simulation (filling a basin + horizontal movement)

Tags: animation

I would like to perform a fluid simulation to analyze its behavior over a distance of 1 meter, for example. My workflow is as follows:

Fill a basin with a fluid (real milk, for example).
Wait for the filling to reach a level X.
Move the basin (which acts as an "effector") over a distance of 1 meter.
In my simulation, when the basin starts moving, the fluid gradually evaporates. It seems like the volume inside the basin disappears or compresses.
My goal is simply to see if the basin overflows or not over a distance x.

Do you have any solutions? I'm struggling a bit despite various tests.

Thank you in advance,
[image: enter link description here]
Link to the Blender file :
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/bcd96cee1b08b40fc6c56e4ec4e6b88620230426102735/9239d8

Comment: clicking on your link did not bring me directly to a download, which is often too suspicious for people to use (help you).  I suggest you use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) if your file is not too large.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't think your fluid is "sloshing through" the container/effector, try increasing the effector thickness -- that needs to be at least 0.5 for some unknown reason as I've posted before.

Here's an example of a container with 0.5 vs. one with 0.6, where the 0.5 has some "slosh though".  You might also find that adding a Solidify modifier (above the effector on the mod stack) might also help.

[image]

this example: [image]